# Combine 4 angularfire2 observables into 1

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

This is my new app.

[image: DB]

Angular fire 2 + Firebase

```js
getErros(start, end): FirebaseListObservable<any>{

      this.lista = this.db.list('/erros/geral',{
          query: {
                  orderByChild: 'titulo',
                  limitToFirst:10,
                  startAt: start,
                  endAt: end
          }
      });

      this.lista2 = this.db.list('/erros/utilsst',{
          query: {
                  orderByChild: 'titulo',
                  limitToFirst:10,
                  startAt: start,
                  endAt: end
          }
      });

      this.lista3 = this.db.list('/erros/utilfac',{
          query: {
                  orderByChild: 'titulo',
                  limitToFirst:10,
                  startAt: start,
                  endAt: end
          }
      });

      this.lista4 = this.db.list('/erros/geral',{
          query: {
                  orderByChild: 'titulo',
                  limitToFirst:10,
                  startAt: start,
                  endAt: end
          }
      });

      this.listafinal = (this.lista && this.lista2 && this.lista3 && this.lista4);

      return this.listafinal;
  }
```

Simple Data Search from firebase but can't get it working. Is there any way to perform this ?

Can't get it working. Only receives data from this.lista4

Comment: what do you want achive here "this.listafinal = (this.lista && this.lista2 && this.lista3 && this.lista4)"

Comment: Get data from 4 different paths. Then send it all to one place

Comment: you want combine four observable into single observable ?

Comment: If you take a look to the DB, there's 4 different paths. And I want to go through all. So yes, I want to combine 4 observables into one i guess....

Comment: Your going to run into an asynchronous issue; if there are 10,000 nodes returned in /geral and 3 nodes in /utilfac it's going to take longer to get the results from /geral. Therefore 'combining' the nodes before all of the data is returned will be a problem. You need to allow Firebase to return the data before working with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using `combineLatest`. using this operator you can combine all four into single observable and this will generate a new value if any one of observable is changed

```
Observable.combineLatest(
  this.db.list('/erros/geral',{
          query: {
                  orderByChild: 'titulo',
                  limitToFirst:10,
                  startAt: start,
                  endAt: end
          }
      }),
  this.db.list('/erros/utilsst',{
          query: {
                  orderByChild: 'titulo',
                  limitToFirst:10,
                  startAt: start,
                  endAt: end
          }
      }),
  this.db.list('/erros/utilfac',{
          query: {
                  orderByChild: 'titulo',
                  limitToFirst:10,
                  startAt: start,
                  endAt: end
          }
      }),
      this.db.list('/erros/utilatas',{
          query: {
                  orderByChild: 'titulo',
                  limitToFirst:10,
                  startAt: start,
                  endAt: end
          }
      })

)
.map(([geral, utilsst, utilfac, utilatas]: [any, any, any, any]) =>
  ({ geral, utilsst, utilfac, utilatas }) // Do add operation here.
)
```

Comment: What should i return ?

Comment: add return statement  to Observable `return  Observable.combineLatest(`

Comment: this.hey = Observable.combineLatest( | and then return this.hey

Comment: There's an error. ERROR Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.

Comment: do a console log and show me output. i think inside map you need update

Comment: i think your new programming. update your map function and let me know if you still face issue `.map(([geral, utilsst, utilfac, utilatas]: [any, any, any, any]) => {
   let result  = [...geral, ...utilsst, ...utilfac, ...utilatas];
   console.log('result',result)
   return result;
}
)`

Comment: Jonny i have another way, would you like to see it ? The only problem is on NgFor

Comment: try this and show me your console.log `.map(([geral, utilsst, utilfac, utilatas]: [any, any, any, any]) => { console.log(geral, utilsst, utilfac, utilatas) } )`

Comment: you can show me. i think the problem is combine result not the ngFor

Comment: https://pastebin.com/dbCtcYQm This way already displays on console as [Object] and its alright but when displaying on the ngFor only 1 appears not the 4

Comment: you can't use merge. it  won't combine observable. see these links and play with them you will understand difference https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/combinelatest.html https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/merge.html

Comment: So help out here with your example

Comment: did you tried this do you got any output `.map(([geral, utilsst, utilfac, utilatas]: [any, any, any, any]) => { console.log(geral, utilsst, utilfac, utilatas) } )`

Comment: try this `.map(([geral, utilsst, utilfac, utilatas]: [any, any, any, any]) =>

 { let result = [geral, utilsst,utilfac,utilatas]; console.log('result',result) 
 
 return result; } )`

Comment: try this .map(([geral, utilsst, utilfac, utilatas]: [any[], any[], any[], any[]]) => { let result = [...geral, ...utilsst, ...utilfac, ...utilatas]; console.log('result',result) return result; } )

Answer (score 0):

I've done some changes on the code.

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireDatabase, FirebaseListObservable } from 'angularfire2/database';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';
import * as Rx from 'rxjs';
@Injectable()
export class ProcurarService {







  constructor(private db: AngularFireDatabase) {
      
   }
  
   hey;
   

  getErros(start, end): FirebaseListObservable<any>{

this.hey = Observable.combineLatest(
  this.db.list('/erros/geral',{
          query: {
                  orderByChild: 'titulo',
                  limitToFirst:10,
                  startAt: start,
                  endAt: end
          }
      }),
  this.db.list('/erros/utilsst',{
          query: {
                  orderByChild: 'titulo',
                  limitToFirst:10,
                  startAt: start,
                  endAt: end
          }
      }),
  this.db.list('/erros/utilfac',{
          query: {
                  orderByChild: 'titulo',
                  limitToFirst:10,
                  startAt: start,
                  endAt: end
          }
      }),
      this.db.list('/erros/utilatas',{
          query: {
                  orderByChild: 'titulo',
                  limitToFirst:10,
                  startAt: start,
                  endAt: end
          }
      })

)
.map(([geral, utilsst, utilfac, utilatas]: [any, any, any, any]) => { let erro = [geral, utilsst,utilfac,utilatas]; console.log(erro); return erro;  } )

return this.hey;

  }


}
```

This way works, [image]

The problem is: [image]

That it doesn't displays the data, and i the searchbar isn't working either..

Comment: the problem here you need create array of Error but your result is array of array error

Comment: Jonny see my new post, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45066677/ngfor-not-displaying-arrays

Comment: ok. did you tried this map(([geral, utilsst, utilfac, utilatas]: [any[], any[], any[], any[]]) => { let result = [...geral, ...utilsst, ...utilfac, ...utilatas]; console.log('result',result) return result; } )

Comment: Yes i tried everything. And by the way, i have to use flatMap since the ngFor cant read a simple map

Comment: I have tried this solution and it does nothing. Did you upgrade the code at all?