# ngFor not displaying arrays

Tags: angular, firebase, rxjs, angularfire2

I have a search service:

```
getErros(start, end): FirebaseListObservable<any>{

this.hey = Rx.Observable.combineLatest(
  this.db.list('/erros/geral',{
          query: {
                  orderByChild: 'titulo',
                  limitToFirst:10,
                  startAt: start,
                  endAt: end
          }
      }),
  this.db.list('/erros/utilsst',{
          query: {
                  orderByChild: 'titulo',
                  limitToFirst:10,
                  startAt: start,
                  endAt: end
          }
      }),
  this.db.list('/erros/utilfac',{
          query: {
                  orderByChild: 'titulo',
                  limitToFirst:10,
                  startAt: start,
                  endAt: end
          }
      }),
      this.db.list('/erros/utilatas',{
          query: {
                  orderByChild: 'titulo',
                  limitToFirst:10,
                  startAt: start,
                  endAt: end
          }
      })

)

const errox = this.hey.flatMap(
    (([geral, utilsst, utilfac, utilatas]: [string, string, string, string]) => {
        let erros = [geral, utilsst,utilfac,utilatas];
        console.log(erros);
        return erros;
    } ))


return errox;

  }
```

And this is where it's called:

```
ngOnInit() {
    
    const errox = this.errosSvc.getErros(this.startAt, this.endAt)
            .subscribe(erros => this.erros = erros)
  }
```

And it's only displaying one Array in the ngFor:

```
<tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let erro of erros">
      <th id="butaoxx" class="col-md-1" style="text-align:center;" scope="row">
        <button id="butaox"  data-toggle="modal" attr.data-target="#{{erro.$key}}"
            class="panel panel-default" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs ">
            Abrir
        </button>
      </th>
      <td style="text-align:center;">{{erro?.titulo}}</td>
      <td style="text-align:center;">{{erro?.tema}}</td>
      <td  style="text-align:center;">{{erro?.subtema}}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
```

I know the others Arrays and the search service is working because I implemented a console.log and the data appears right and the search works. The only problem is that the ngFor only displays data from the last Array which in this case is "utilatas".

Comment: can you post result for your " console.log(erros);"  add new console log inside component ngOnInit()   const errox = this.errosSvc.getErros(this.startAt, this.endAt)
            .subscribe(erros => {console.log("erros",erros);this.erros = erros})

Comment: http://prntscr.com/fuy0ui, you can see there's one object because i searched by it. The problem is that ngFor isn't recognizing that array

Comment: @Jonnysai if i use only .map this shows like this http://prntscr.com/fuy5ff

Comment: use .map and inside component try like this `const errox = this.errosSvc.getErros(this.startAt, this.endAt) .subscribe(erros => {console.log("erros",erros); let flatten= [].concat.apply([], erros);
console.log('flatten',flatten); this.erros = flatten})`

Comment: the above code flatten your array of array into just array so that your ngfor will work

Comment: It worked man, thanks a lot!

Comment: finally :) i posted solution as answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149108/discussion-between-diogo-alexandre-and-jonnysai).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need flatten your array of array into array

```
    const errox = this.errosSvc.getErros(this.startAt, this.endAt) .subscribe(erros => {
 let flatten= [].concat.apply([], erros); 
console.log('flatten',flatten);
 this.erros = flatten})
```

Comment: Thanks you brother! Do you have Skype?

Comment: yup why ? you can give me email id.

Comment: For other questions and that, give me your email then!

Answer (score 0):

You instantiate `erros` array asynchronously inside the `this.errosSvc.getErros` subscription, that is why it only returns partial data.

Instead, try iterating through the subscription result itself, like this:

```
<tr *ngFor="let erro of errox | async">
  ...
</tr>


public errox: FirebaseListObservable<any>;

ngOnInit() {

  this.errox = this.errosSvc.getErros(this.startAt, this.endAt);
}
```